# What is necessary to enable cscope to use VIM as the editor with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, gvim 7.3, and in my .bashrc file I have the following:

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR=vim
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim
```

However, when I run cscope, and select one of the items meeting my match, the file is opened using VI. Is there anything else needed for VIM support? Are there any resource files that are needed and what settings are needed in them? 
Thanks!

EDIT: I did verify running echo on $EDITOR and $VISUAL, that they are set to vim.

Comment: i think you just install it, generate a bunch of cscope output file, then `:cs add that_file_name` when you open vi.

Comment: The `vi` and `vim` commands point to the same executable so there's no problem here.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr It sounds like you trying to explain how to open cscope from within vi, is that correct? I am trying to open files from cscope using gvim. When the files are opened using gvim, you can open multiple entries simultaneously from cscope, not to mention that gvim is more powerful than vi.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr is correct. You can query cscope directly from inside of Vim. Just add a cscope connection via `:cscope add filename` then you can run `:cscope` and it will give you a list of command you can run on the codebase

Comment: it's the same. i've done it thousands of time without any problems. i didn't even modify `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
    sudo update-alternatives –config editor

Vi is usually symlinked to vim.tiny too

Comment: The -config flag was not appreciated.                                ~$ sudo update-alternatives –config editor
[sudo] password for userxxx: 
update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `–config'

Comment: I just happened to reread this and noticed that 'config' is prefaced by two dashes, not one. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

After discussing this with a coworker, I realized that I meant gvim. The confusion arose because when downloading gvim, you request the vim-gnome. Replacing vim with gvim gave me the functionality I was looking for. Is there a way to update the question?